# The new page do not scroll to top when the state changed success in angular4 with ui-router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I got a problem as title.

I found the solution in `AngularJS` and use `autoscroll` directive on `<ui-view></ui-view>`.

But I want to find the solution in `Angular`, and I can't find that.

I need help....

Answer (score 0):

I did this hack, in `AppComponent`:

`app.component.html`

```
<router-outlet (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
public onDeactivate() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

But maybe exists more beautiful way to solve this.

Comment: This solution must be used in every component right?@@

Comment: updated answer, in every component that has `<router-outlet>`

Comment: I got it.
But sorry, I use `ui-router` . Not native router in angular...Orz